# How to join geodataframe itself

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, shapely

My goal is to calculate the distance from a point and the nearest point, so I thought of using `geopandas` function `sjoin_nearest`. Using this function I get all the distances to zero, which is quite normal because I had to ignore the point itself. Any idea to resolve this problem ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'long': [-73.582003, -73.587419, -73.586842, -73.587095],
    'lat': [45.504592, 45.503420, 45.503720, 45.502097]})

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.long, df.lat))
gdf = gdf.set_crs('epsg:32188')

gdf.sjoin_nearest(gdf.copy(), distance_col="distance")
```

Comment: How many points do you have in your dataframe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the solution of [How to use geopandas or shapely to find nearest point in same geodataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56532397/835653) with a for loop ( generally not recommended with Pandas).

```
df = gpd.read_file("points.shp") 
df["nearest_geom"]= None
df["dist"]= None

for index, row in df.iterrows():
     point = row.geometry
     multipoint = df.drop(index, axis=0).geometry.unary_union
     queried_geom, nearest_geom = nearest_points(point, multipoint)
     d = queried_geom.distance(nearest_geom)
     df.loc[index, "nearest_geom"] = str(nearest_geom)
     df.loc[index, "dist"] = d

print(df)
     id          geometry             nearest_geom         dist
0    1   POINT (7900.000 6700.000)   POINT (7300 6900)    632.455532
1    2   POINT (10700.000 5100.000)  POINT (10900 5700)   632.455532
2    3   POINT (9500.000 6900.000)   POINT (8900 6100)   1000.000000
3    4   POINT (13900.000 3700.000)  POINT (12500 3100)  1523.154621
4    5   POINT (11300.000 7100.000)  POINT (10900 5700)  1456.021978
5    6   POINT (12500.000 3100.000)  POINT (13900 3700)  1523.154621
6    7   POINT (10700.000 4100.000)  POINT (10700 5100)  1000.000000
7    8   POINT (11500.000 4900.000)  POINT (10700 5100)   824.621125
8    9   POINT (8900.000 6100.000)   POINT (9700 5700)    894.427191
9   10   POINT (10900.000 5700.000)  POINT (10700 5100)   632.455532
10  11   POINT (7300.000 6900.000)   POINT (7900 6700)    632.455532
11  12   POINT (9700.000 5700.000)   POINT (8900 6100)    894.427191
```

Or you can use [scipy spatial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.html) or [scikit-learn (Nearest Neighbors)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html)`

```
x = [i.x for i in df.geometry]
y = [i.y for i in df.geometry]
coords = np.stack((x, y), axis=1)
# scipy spatial
import scipy.spatial
kdt = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(coords]) 
distances, indices = kdt.query(coords, 2)
# or 
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
kdt = KDTree(coords, leaf_size=30, metric='euclidean')
distances, indices = kdt.query(coords, k=2)       
# or
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(coords)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(coords)
```

And after:

```
df['ind1']= indices[:,0]
df['ind2']= indices[:,1]
df['dist']= distances[:,1]
print(df)


    id          geometry             ind1  ind2     dist
0    1   POINT (7900.000 6700.000)     0    10   632.455532
1    2   POINT (10700.000 5100.000)    1     9   632.455532
2    3   POINT (9500.000 6900.000)     2     8  1000.000000
3    4   POINT (13900.000 3700.000)    3     5  1523.154621
4    5   POINT (11300.000 7100.000)    4     9  1456.021978
5    6   POINT (12500.000 3100.000)    5     3  1523.154621
6    7   POINT (10700.000 4100.000)    6     1  1000.000000
7    8   POINT (11500.000 4900.000)    7     1   824.621125
8    9   POINT (8900.000 6100.000)     8    11   894.427191
9   10   POINT (10900.000 5700.000)    9     1   632.455532
10  11   POINT (7300.000 6900.000)    10     0   632.455532
11  12   POINT (9700.000 5700.000)    11     8   894.427191
```

Comment: does the cKDTree-based method work geographic (lon/lat) coordinates?